# Embedding Tensorflow Lite model in my simple Android app

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I developed this simple camera app in Android to simply show the camera preview. I am new to Tensorflow Lite and would like to use a `.tflite` model in my app. Specifically, I need to embed this [segmentation](https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-models/image_segmenter/selfie_segmenter/float16/latest/selfie_segmenter.tflite) model in the app and apply it on the frame so to get the resulting output mask and show it on the preview. How can I add this to my code below?

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSurfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            startCameraPreview();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
    }

    private void startCameraPreview() {
        try {
            int frontCameraId = -1;
            int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
                Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
                if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    frontCameraId = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (frontCameraId == -1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Front camera not found");
                return;
            }

            mCamera = Camera.open(frontCameraId);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); // Set orientation for vertical view
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // No implementation needed
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (mSurfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error stopping camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // No implementation needed
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startCameraPreview();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```